# Compare Explicit formulas

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I found two formulas from the question, and I have to show that $(1)$ equation is smaller or equal to $(2)$ equation. They are,

> $(1)$ $n! + (n-1)! + (n-2)! + ... + (n-n)!$
>
> $(2)$ $1 + n + n(n-1) + n(n-1)(n-2) + ... + n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)...(n-n)$

Now, I want to write them as explicit formulas, then compare as I mentioned. But, I can't continue from here.

Comment: $(1)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n k!\\(2)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{n!}{k!}$

Comment: @user1448742 Thanks. How can I prove that $(1)$ is smaller or equal to $(2)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you reverse the order of the terms in both sums then you'll see that
the first expression is equal to
$$ 
\sum_{k=0}^n k!
$$
and the second expressions is equal to
$$ 
\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{n!}{(n-k)!}
$$
Now use that for $0 \le k \le n$,
$$
  \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} = { n \choose k }\ge 1 \, .
$$